# Access linux device through bridged interface

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables, bridge

I'm currently trying to set up a device with a bridge in my network. The device used for the Bridge has two eth interfaces and a wlan interface.

I managed to create the bridge from eth1 to wlan0. The bridge itself is working fine, I can ping the PC2 connected to the bridge at eth1 from the wlan0

Right now I can only use eth0 for ssh or accessing its page set up with lighttpd.

Is there a way to configure the network so I can use the wlan0-interface too? I tried to look into iptables but I could not find any solution.

That's the setup:

```
PC 1                       Bridge                  PC 2
-----------------------------------------------------
Lan--------------------->|eth0   |
                         |eth1   |--------------->Lan
                         |wlan   |
```

Edit:

Trying to go a bit more into detail. Both PC2 and the Bridge-device have installed lighttpd and own a homepage which can be accessed by their IP.

The bridge looks like this

```
$ brctl show 
bridge name        bridge id              stp enabled          interfaces
br0                8000.1cba8ca5cb94      no                   eth1
                                                               wlan0
```

Know, what I want: While I'm connected via wlan0: insert the PC2's IP into the browser and view the Homepage -> this worked

While I'm connected via wlan0: insert the Bridge-device's IP into the browser and view the Homepage -> this does not work ... I guess because that's because I had to "ifconfig wlan 0.0.0.0 down" before creating the bridge.

I hope it gets more clear now... :)

Answer (score 0):

Most wireless devices do not allow traffic to be sent over them with a non-local MAC.

I would suggest just not bridging your wireless device.

You might be able to get around this with `ebtables` NAT. External URLs are usually discouraged on the StackExchange network, but the following is a good source of explanation and example config and has been around for years:

https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC

Comment: Right. There are two different LAN technologies in play (IEEE 802.3 and IEEE 802.11), so you can't use a transparent bridge; it requires a translational bridge. You can bridge different IEEE LAN types, but you need a translational bridge. It used to be common to bridge 802.3 (ethernet) and 802.5 (token ring) with translational bridges. Transparent bridges only work with the same LAN type.

Comment: That's not the reason though. The Linux bridge will pass Ethernet frames from an Ethernet 802.3 device to a Wireless 802.11 device. The problem is that the firmware on the wireless device probably has a rule which says "if Source Mac is not My MAC, drop the traffic".

Comment: Since one side is ethernet, and one side is Wi-Fi, the frames must be translated from ethernet frames to Wi-Fi frames, or vice versa. Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) is not ethernet (802.3), or any other LAN type. A translational bridge translates from on LAN type to another LAN type. I can believe that Linux can do the translation, and it can probably do the translation to token ring, FDDI, etc., too..

Comment: That is Layer 1 receive and transmit, on Linux that is handled by the device driver transparently to upper layers. By the time the traffic reaches the bridge, the traffic is a Layer 2 Ethernet frame. The bridge just knows "ports" and the underlying Layer 1 device type of the port is abstracted away from the bridge.

Comment: The Wi-Fi frame header is different than the ethernet frame header. An ethernet frame won't work on Wi-Fi, or vice versa. The frame must be translated from one to the other.